# Can different type of objects(sub-class types) added on a List (if type of List is their common superclass)?

Tags: java, list, object, arraylist

Recently, I saw this similar article about different objects on List *(please don't mark as duplicate)*
[java ArrayList contains different objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566983/java-arraylist-contains-different-objects)
In the article it is mentioned that in order to be done, one must implent a common class for these items.

However in the following piece of code, classes of aforementioned objects simply use `extends` not `implement` for the class **Employee**

And I wondered if it could work that way

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SalariedEmployee emp1 = new SalariedEmployee();
    HourlyEmployee emp2 = new HourlyEmployee();

    emp1.setName("Jack Smith");
    emp1.setAm("72154f");
    emp1.setSalary(3000);

    emp2.setName("John Smith");
    emp2.setAm("13521a");
    emp2.setHoursWorked(300);
    emp2.setHourlyPayment(4);

    List<Employee> emp = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    emp.add(emp1);
    emp.add(emp2);

   for(Employee item:emp){
       System.out.println("Employee ID:"+item.getID());
       System.out.println("Employee Name:"+item.getName());
       System.out.println("Employee AM:"+item.getAm());
       System.out.println("Employee Payment:"+item.payment());
}
```

Comment: When i used a non-generic syntax List emp = new ArrayList();
I got a compiler warning?

Comment: Well, simply try to run your code ;)

Comment: were there any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to make a list of the Employee class, which you have and will work fine.

```
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
```

The reason you should bound instead of directly declaring `List<Employee>` is usually due to passing parameters:

```
public void doSomething(List<? extends Employee> list) {...}
public void doSomethingElse(List<Employee> list) {...}
```

Let's say we have two lists, `List<Employee> employees` and `List<SalariedEmployee> semployed`, the result of calling these methods would be:

```
doSomething(employees); //fine
doSomething(semployed); //fine

dosomethingElse(employees); //fine
dosomethingElse(semployed); //error!
```

By not bounding you are limiting yourself to strictly being of objects `Employee` type, instead of all of its subclasses.

Comment: I don't understand how this work and why would I need to do that.
Could you please explain me futher?

Comment: With this you are "bounding" the types of classes that you allow for your list object. There are some good tutorials around [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) as well as [Wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html). I'll expand more on my answer as to why you should bound

Comment: shouldn't it be List<? extends Employee> employees = new ArrayList<? extends Employee>(); or the syntax changes at "bounding"?

Comment: Aha, I used Java 7 syntax for that. If you are using Java 6 then you will need to respecify the `<>`, yes.

Comment: so I am not able to call directly the subclass of the object of the List, but I am sorry , I cant still figure this out , 
Isn't the purpose of the list to be fully automated, if I was calling every single subclass type,(it would have the same result) but don't I write more lines of code?

Comment: With this you write less, because you won't have to write methods for specific subclass types with bounds

Comment: You would *not* use this when creating a new list, because then you can't add anything to the list. Also, I'm not sure it answers the question...

Comment: @immibis that's correct, might've been a brianfart back then. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Class becomes a type of some other type by

- `extending` it if this other type is *class* or
- `implementing` it if this type if *interface*.

So yes, since both `SalariedEmployee` and `HourlyEmployee` are types of `Employee` (both types `extends Employee` as you mentioned in question) your list

```
List<Employee> emp = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

should be able to store instances of such derived classes without problem.

Comment: Is it the same type by extending or implementing?
In other words is the type of a superclass same as the type of a class interface at the same level of hierarchy with the other classes?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly but maybe this will help. You can think of classes and interfaces are types. Way to make your class also type of some interface is via keyword `implements` and adding implementation to methods from interface. If you want to make your class also type of some other class you use `extends` keyword.